# Algorithm - Alphabetize list row wise instead of column wise - Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, loops

I have the list of string alphabetically ordered like the following: 
AA, AB, AC, BA, BD, CD, DE, DF, EA, ED, FA, FB, GA, GB
When I loop over the list, it alphabetize like the following:
AA ---- AB ---- AC ---- BA
BA ---- BD ---- CD ---- DE
DF ---- EA ---- ED ---- FA
FB ---- GA ---- GB
that's because I am looping like this

```
loop over list
<div class="col-md-3"> list element here...</div>
```

I want the output like the following:

AA ---- BA ---- DF ---- FB
AB ---- BD ---- EA ---- GA
AC ---- CD ---- ED ---- GB
BA ---- DE ---- FA

So, what will be my logic to output like this in bootstrap?

Thanks,

Comment: "I have the list of string ": what do you mean? An array of strings? An object containing....? Please, could you clarify?

Comment: Consider that an array...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$arr = array("AA","AB", "AC", "BA", "BD", "CD", "DE");
$d = count($arr) / 4;
$tr = floor ($d);
$fraction = ($d - floor($d)) * 4;

$j = 0; 
while (true) {
    $html ="";
    $i = $j;
    $f = $fraction;
    if ($f == 0 && $j == $tr) {
        break;
    }

    for ($col = 0; $col < 4; $col++) {

        $html .= $arr[$i] . " "; // apply html / bootstrap classes etc here

        $i += $tr + ($f-- > 0 ? 1 : 0);
        if ($col < 3 && $i >= count($arr) || ($f == 0 && $j == $tr)) {
            echo $html . "<br>";
            $html = "";
            break;
        };
    }

    if ($html == "") {
        break;
    } else {
        echo $html . "<br>";
    }
    $j++;
}
```